# XML XSD Regex for xsd:NMTOKEN

Tags: regex, xml, xsd

I am struggling to come up with a regex that will handle the NMTOKEN definition;

> The type xsd:NMTOKEN represents a single string token. xsd:NMTOKEN
>   values may consist of letters, digits, periods (.), hyphens (-),
>   underscores (_), and colons (:). They may start with any of these
>   characters. xsd:NMTOKEN has a whiteSpace facet value of collapse, so
>   any leading or trailing whitespace will be removed. However, no
>   whitespace may appear within the value itself.

I am new to Regex and not sure of a good place to start with the criteria on this regex

Here is the example i was working off; `\^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-:]*$\g`

Comment: Please add what you tried and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Could you please provide an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was really close but because of the way the pattern was being compiled, i needed to escape the escape (because it's received in a string format)

So i went from;

```
pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9._\-:]*$"
```

to...

```
pattern: "^[a-zA-Z0-9._\\-:]*$"
```

I wouldn't have had this issue if i was writing the regex directly in it's use, but because it was being rendered from a JSON feed, as a string, it needed escaping (twice)